# What are the characteristics of the Macedonian language in this quote referring to?

Tags: self-learning, grammar, slavic-languages

I'm trying to learn Macedonian and one if the resources out there was paraphrased as saying the following about the Macedonian language:

> Belamaric-Wilsey says that the majority of Macedonian-language learners using the center’s resources are English native speakers. The most challenging features of the Macedonian language for them are the doubling of the object, the verb aspect (perfective vs. imperfective), and the perfect tense. Still, she says, if you are motivated enough, you will make progress, especially if you are visiting Macedonia.

What does this mean?

1. Doubling of the Object
2. Verb aspect (Perfective vs. Imperfective)
3. Perfect tense

And, how does Macedonian's handling of the concepts differ from English's?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. This site is intended for questions about learning or teaching languages, but your question appears to be about the meaning of specific linguistic terms that are not related to language learning, and about a comparison between the features of two languages. Could you please review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question may fit better on [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Doubling of the Object- this probably refers to the use of two object pronouns in a sentence, specifically when describing the use of direct and indirect object pronouns with a verb.
2. Verb aspect (Perfective vs. Imperfective)- This probably describes the distinction between two different aspects for employing the past tense.  In most languages, this distinction is generalized by a repeated action in the past (imperfective) and an action not repeated in the past (perfective).
3. Perfect tense- this could refer to either the English present, past, and future tense employing a form of "have" + past participle.  Or it could refer to the perfective aspect referred to above.

Unfortunately, some of these terms do have multiple meanings, so it is not the most carefully thought-out grammatical description.

Comment: And here I thought I couldn't be more confused!  Thanks for your answer, though. Looks like I have a lot more fundamentals to learn!